# format a lengthy number with commas in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a requirement to convert the very lengthy amount to a `comma separated value in oracle`. I was searching in google. but I got some solutions which works only for small numbers. But not for lengthy number. Below is the solution I have. But not working properly. I was getting `############`... if I run the below.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(6965854565787645667634565432234565432345643265432345643242087,
'99G999G999G9999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=",."') as test
FROM dual;
```

**Desired output:**

`6,965,854,565,787,645,667,634,565,432,234,565,432,345,643,265,432,345,643,242,087`

Please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is that number coming from, and as what data type? You can do this if it's already a string, but as mathguy says as a number it's beyond Oracle's allowed precision.

Answer (score 2):

Please check if below query can help.

```
SELECT ltrim(regexp_replace('00'
  || '6965854565787645667634565432234565432345643265432345643242087', '(...)', ',\1' ),',|0') AS t
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Numbers in Oracle can't have more than 38 significant digits. You have many more than that.

If I may, what kind of "amount" is that? My understanding is that Oracle was designed to handle real-life values. What possible meaning is there to the sample number you posted?

**Added**: Original poster in a comment (below) stated that he is getting the same error with a shorter number, only 34 digits.

Two issues. First, the format model must have at least the needed number of digits (of 9's). `to_char(100000, '9G999')` will produce the output `####` because the format model allows only 4 digits, but the input is 6 digits.

Then, after that is corrected, the output may still look incorrect in the front-end application, like SQL*Plus. In SQL*Plus the default width of a number column is 10 (I believe). That can be changed to 38, for example with the command `set numwidth 38`. In other front-ends, like Toad and SQL Developer, the default numeric width is a setting that can be changed through the graphical user interface.

**More added** - actually the result of `to_char` is a string, and by default strings of any length should be displayed OK in any front-end, so the numeric width is probably irrelevant. (And, in any case, it does not affect the displaying of strings, including the result of `to_char()`.)

Comment: That number is more than the number of atoms in the universe... ;)

Comment: I tried with this number which is less than 38 digits. 6965854565787645667634565432234565 It still shows the same #####...

Comment: @SreeBhanu - OK, I added to my initial answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT TO_CHAR(
    6676345654322345654323456432654323456, 
    '999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999',
'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=",."') as test FROM dual

    TEST
    ------------------------------------------------------------
       6,676,345,654,322,345,654,323,456,432,654,323,456
```

Comment: I am not sure that works.  If you actually tried to use the number the OP gave us, you'd get an ORA-01481 (invalid number format model).

Comment: That's using a number 38 digits long, as per his update.

Comment: The `column` command is not needed; by default SQL\*Plus will expand to accommodate the longest string in a string column.

Comment: @mathguy. Ha! Did not know that. Always learning ;)  I'll edit my post appropriately...

Answer (score 1):

@AlexPoole pointed out that perhaps your input is a string.

I didn't get that vibe; but if in fact your input IS a string, and if you know the length is no more than 99 digits, you could do something like below. If your strings can be longer than 99, replace 99 below with a sufficiently large multiple of 3. (Or, you can replace it with a calculated value, `3 * ceil(length(str)/3)`).

```
with
     inputs ( str ) as (
       select '12345678912345' from dual
     )
-- WITH clause is only for testing/illustration, not part of the solution
select ltrim(regexp_replace(lpad(str, 99, ','), '(.{3})', ',\1'), ',') as test
from   inputs;

TEST
------------------
12,345,678,912,345
```